# How comes plotting affine curve as shadows of gray modulo integer resembles its real locus?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, curves, image-processing

Let $f(x,y)$ be polynomial with integer coefficients.

Pick integer $n>2$.

Let $M$ be $n \times n$ matrix. Set $M_{i,j}=f(i,j) \mod n$.

Plot $M$ as bitmap in shadows of gray where larger value is lighter
and smaller is darker. (Zero is black).

Experiments suggest the resulting plot in shadows of gray
sometimes resembles the real locus of the affine curve $f(x,y)=0$.

> Is this true?
>
> If this is true how to explain it?

Actually such relation between discrete and continuous surprises
dumb me.

---

Here are some plots for $n=213$ done in Sage.
$$x^2+y^2-1$$
[image]

$$x^2+2y^2-1$$

[image]

$$x^2-y^2-1$$

[image]

$$x^3-y^2-1$$ (might be counterexample)

[image]

$ x^2+y^2-1$, white is zero, black is nonzero.

[image]

$x^2+2y^2-1$ with colormap 'gnuplot', check sage's documentation.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the zero locus of the curve seems to be recurrent (scaled and translated) throughout the plot?

Comment: Part of the explanation is surely that $x^2+y^2-1$ is symmetric in pretty much every way imaginable. This is also why $x^3-y^2-1$ doesn't work; there no symmetry between $x$ and $-x$ values, and no symmetry between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @user2520938 I edited adding $x^2+2y^2-1$. Your first question appears subjective to me -- judge for yourself. Agree about the symmetry.

Comment: This happens where $df/dx$ and $df/dy$ simultaneously vanish. Then you can see "half"-patterns where those derivatives are of order $2$, etc.

Comment: @mercio What is "this" in "this happens"? There are too many patterns IMHO.